# How to check whether a stored procedure has completed all the inserting/deleting/updating operations?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, return-value

I have got a stored procedure in SQL Server 2008 and it does quite a fair amount of inserting / deleting / updating operations.

Now I am wondering if there would be any way that I might be able to detect whether or not a stored procedure has completed **ALL Inserting / Deleting / Updating operations**.

Also, I understand that there can be a returned value from a stored procedure, which in this case here can be a statusCode (0/1). But through some of my experiments, I found that the statusCode always would get returned immediately once the execution of the stored procedure was finished, while in the mean time, inserting / deleting / updating was actually still running. So what should I do here to see the statusCode only get returned when inserting / deleting / updating operations have all been completed?

Thanks.

Code Structure:

```
BEGIN
    DECLARE @statusCode
    SET @statusCode = 0

    -- Loop through all tables in a given database
    -- using cursor
    -- do Insert / Update/ Delete operations

    SET @statusCode = 1
    SELECT @statusCode 
END
```

Comment: It is considered polite to accept answers to your questions. To a large extent, you have neglected to do so. You may want to go back and accept answers to your previous questions. This may motivate further help from other StackOverflow users.

Comment: @Rodrigo Thanks for the reminder. Yeah I have marked the answer for this post and will review previous posts and mark those that haven't been marked yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the stored procedure returns, all operations for that call are complete.

You have **not** seen operations continuing after a stored procedure finishes unless *another* connection is making changes too. For one, it would break A in [ACID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID)

Comment: @gbn Hmm that's interesting. I ran the stored procedure in SQL server 2008 and actually I'd seen it return the value even before query execution was complete.

Comment: @woodykiddy: this is impossible. It is that simple.

Comment: @gbn I had a look at the code in that stored procedure, and I found the variable `set @statusCode=0 ` at the very beginning of it and `set @statusCode=1  select @statusCode ` at the bottom. Technically, is it really returning a value?

Comment: Yes, a single row, single column recordset. Maybe expand your question with code (don't shorten it toomuch) and explain your symptoms. Do you have multiple callers to this procedure but only need one to run it at once?

Comment: @gbn I have put a block of code in my question, where you can get a basic idea of what that stored procedure is doing.

Comment: @woodykiddy: in which case, the `SELECT @statusCode` won't be hit until all other statements have executed